# Unable to set input value in JavaScript after each reload

Tags: javascript, forms, input

This is the code I am using in Chrome's Developer Console:

```
document.querySelector('input').value = 'Some URL';
```

The code runs without any error. However, the value of the input is not updated. The input shows the same old value. I can click buttons easily using

```
document.querySelector('button[value="true"]').click();
```

So, why are the values not being updated?

UPDATE: I am using this code [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/). Before commenting that the code works please try it on the page I linked to.

UPDATE 2: I am also unable to debug multiple URLs at once using a for loop. Here is my code:

```
for(var i=0;i<50;i++){
  setInterval(function () {
    var url = 'http://myurl/goes/here/?n=' + i;
    console.log(url);
    document.querySelector('input.inputtext').value = url;
    document.querySelector('button[value="true"]').click();
  }, 10000);
}
```

However, it sets the value of input to `http://myurl/goes/here/?n=49` and then reloads the page only once with that value. What I want is reload the page after each URL update so that all the URLs can be scraped at once.

Comment: works all right: https://jsfiddle.net/dnx3L4wv/ ?

Comment: You might consider posting your entire code as this [appears to work just fine](http://jsbin.com/keyawalino/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you provided, it looks like you are targeting the wrong element (i.e. the search box at the top as opposed to the main `<input />` element) as seen by the result of your code below :

[image]

You can resolve this by making your selector more specific within the [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) function to target the appropriate element :

```
document.querySelector('input.inputtext').value = 'Some URL';
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed the other input. I will accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Could you please help me with one more doubt?

Comment: Sure. What's the issue?

Comment: I actually wanted to debug multiple URLs at once using a for loop but it only executes on the last URL. I am updating the question with more code will that be fine?

Comment: If you wanted to target multiple elements, you'll need to use the `querySelectorAll()` function instead of `querySelector()`.

Comment: No, that's not the issue. I am adding more code to the question. :)

Comment: I don't necessarily know if that is going to be possible. Clicking your button to cause the scrape is going to refresh your page, which will wipe out your existing Javascript call / loop. If this supported multiple URLs at once, then you could do something similar to what you mention, but it doesn't look like it from this point.

Comment: But I have checked preserve log in console. Will it still erase everything?

Answer (score 0):

Its look like there might be another INPUT element exist before the one that you expect to update.

[document#querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector);

> Returns the first element within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes|by first element in document markup and iterating through sequential nodes by order of amount of child nodes) that matches the specified group of selectors

So,try to be more specific either by given unique id or class to your input element.